# What's Instagram's /media/ used for?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have been trying to figure out what this is used for.

What's the difference between using:

http://www.instagram.com/test

and

http://www.instagram.com/test/media

Why does the /media exist? What is its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The diference between http://www.instagram.com/test and http://www.instagram.com/test/media is the web response

1. http://www.instagram.com/test
   This url give **visual information**, because you can see the pictures.
   [image]
2. http://www.instagram.com/test/media 
   This url give you **information to developer** ( [json data](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)) like this.

   [image]

   **This is information about your first image you can check.**